# How to update column values based on new values created from macro?

Tags: vba, excel

Apologise for the ambigious title.

I currently have a Workbook in Excel, which has 5 sheets. Each sheet is interdependent. The workbook is used to workout profit, based on labour productivity, costs, new products sold etc.

On the main worksheet, where parameters can be modified, profit is displayed for **10 Years.** 10 Years is the default number of years which I forecast for. However, using the following macros, I can add and remove years (Extend forecast and Reduce) Starting from the initial 10 years.

To extend years:

```
Sub YearsNumberExtension()

    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim DelCnt As Integer
    DelCnt = Sheets("Clients Control Panel").Range("E17").Value
    Dim copyCol As Range
    Dim DestRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employees")

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Set copyCol = .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol), .Cells(lastRow, LastCol))

        Set DestRange = .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol), .Cells(lastRow, LastCol + DelCnt))

        copyCol.AutoFill Destination:=DestRange, Type:=xlFillDefault

    End With

  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PL")

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Set copyCol = .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol), .Cells(lastRow, LastCol))

        Set DestRange = .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol), .Cells(lastRow, LastCol + DelCnt))

        copyCol.AutoFill Destination:=DestRange, Type:=xlFillDefault

    End With


  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contracts")

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Set copyCol = .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol), .Cells(lastRow, LastCol))

        Set DestRange = .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol), .Cells(lastRow, LastCol + DelCnt))

        copyCol.AutoFill Destination:=DestRange, Type:=xlFillDefault

    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employee Time")

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Set copyCol = .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol), .Cells(lastRow, LastCol))

        Set DestRange = .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol), .Cells(lastRow, LastCol + DelCnt))

        copyCol.AutoFill Destination:=DestRange, Type:=xlFillDefault

    End With

End Sub
```

To reduce years

```
Sub YearsNumberReduction()
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim DelCnt As Integer
DelCnt = Sheets("Clients Control Panel").Range("E19").Value
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contracts")
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If LastCol >= DelCnt Then
        .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol - DelCnt + 1), .Cells(1, LastCol)).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
End With


With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employee Time")
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If LastCol >= DelCnt Then
        .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol - DelCnt + 1), .Cells(1, LastCol)).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employees")
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If LastCol >= DelCnt Then
        .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol - DelCnt + 1), .Cells(1, LastCol)).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PL")
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If LastCol >= DelCnt Then
        .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol - DelCnt + 1), .Cells(1, LastCol)).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

When I execute either macro, they add or delete column years N number of times, specified in the main spreadsheet where I adjust various paramters.

Here, N was 4, so from 10 years, it added 4 years, after I ran the macro.

[image]

However, on the main page where I overview all the statistics, the number of years remain 10, not 14.

[image]

I want to make sure that the number of years on the main panel, mirrors the number of years in the Profit Sheet (PL) as it as dynamic and I can add/remove years using the following macros. What would be a feasable way to do this? (currently its fixed and only limited to 10 years, where I link them using a hlookup function)

USING a solution:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this formula in place of `Year 0`, `Year 1`, `Year 2 ...` in the main tab.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(PL!$1:$1,MATCH("Year " &ROW()-1,PL!$1:$1,0)),"")
```

Adjust the `Row()-1` to whatever row `Year 0` will start on, then drag down for as many rows as needed.

When the macro inserts or columns in the PL tab the years will properly display in the main tab.

Comment: Thanks! Ive extended it by two years, however only one year was added. I suppose I added the formula correctly? As well as I think the hlookup function restricts to the array specified, so it cant take profit from year 11 and onwards. Are there any suggestions for this? Sorry if I don't make it clear enough P.S attached images

Comment: @gcat - wrap the `HLOOKUP` in `IFERROR` so it only shows what is found  and also extend it's column lookup as far as you need. As far as "I've extended it by two years, however only one year was added* - this doesn't show in your example, so I don't know what you mean. works perfectly for me.

Comment: Cheers. I extended the hlookup and wrapped it in an iferror function. Weirdly, it looks like it only goes up until year 11 and I have to manually autofill the profit number. Do you have any idea why it stops working after 11 years? I think i've made a mistake, ill just attempt to figure it out

Comment: In addition, if I drag the formula it seems to be working, but using the macro, it only works up to year 11

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the macros at all? Can't you just use an `if` to return your cell formula or `""`? So let's say your number of years is in a cell named `years_param` and I'll use XXX to represent your current cell formulae on the Employees and PL sheets etc then on those sheets replace the formulae with

```
=IF(ROW() - 4 <= years_param, XXX, "")
```

I'm assuming your data starts on row 4, I might be off by one but the formula should give you the general idea.

Then you can easily do something very similar for your TOTAL PROFIT column so something like (assuming year 0 is on row 29, adjust accordingly):

```
=IF(ROW()-29 <= years_param, "Year "&ROW()-29, "")
```

and now add an `IF` that checks if that columns is empty before your `HLOOKUP`:

```
=IF(A29=="","",HLOOKUP(...
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, im required to use those maros. I see your solution, but I was wondering whether it would be possible to get a peice of code, which not only inserts columns as you want to extend the number of years, but also adds the corresponding rows on the main spreadsheet, where the total number of years and the corresponding profits are aggregated.

Comment: @gcat this will do that, just drag the formulae down a bit further than you need. You might have to change some of the `ROW()`s for `COLUMN()`